# NavMeshAgent first rotate to target direction and than move to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small space game in 3D, but it looks awful when my ship is rotating in the middle of movement
So can someone please help me with code ? I need to rotate to that position and than move to it. (And i forgot to say, that rotation needs to be on Y axis)

Here is my code for that movement.

```
NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}
void Update()
{
    
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to stop the agents rotation.

this is the code:

```
NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}
void Update()
{
    
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        agent.updateRotation = false;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

And I also have a more efficient way for you to check if the player is on **Ground**.
Here is what you should do instead of

`hit.collider.tag == "Ground`

First, make a Layer named "Ground" (anything... depends on you).
Then, add a LayerMask in the script above the NavMeshAgent. `public LayerMask groundLayer`
And in the `if` statement
do this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundLayer))
        {
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
        }
```

What this does is, it only considers the click on objects with the selected layer.The plus point here is that you can select multiple layers in the Inspector.
And do not forget to select the layer in the Inspector.

Thank you! <3